# Sending dynamic values inside context in nativescript

Tags: http, nativescript

i'm using nativescript to build a basic app but i'm stuck sending the context between pages.
I'm listing a serie of items in page1 that i get from an http request and what i want to achieve is send the id of the item into the context to make an http request and render the response in page2.
Here is my approach:

page1.xml (this page is injected into a tabviewitem)

```
<StackLayout class="tab-content" loaded="onViewLoaded">
    <GridLayout rows="auto, *">
        <ListView items="{{ motels }}"
                  row="1"
                  id="motelsList"
                  motelId="{{ id }}"
                  name="{{ name }}"
                  itemTap="goToMotelDetail">
            <ListView.itemTemplate>
                <GridLayout columns="auto, *">
                    <GridLayout columns="auto" rows="auto" class="icon-wrap">
                        <Image width="70" height="70" src="http://fpoimg.com/70x70" stretch="fill" css="icon-image" />
                    </GridLayout>
                    <StackLayout col="1" verticalAlignment="center">
                        <Label text="{{ name }}" textWrap="true" class="motel-name" />
                        <Label text="{{ address }}" textWrap="true" class="motel-address" />
                    </StackLayout>                   
                </GridLayout>
            </ListView.itemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <ActivityIndicator busy="{{ isLoading }}" row="1" horizontalAlignment="center" />
    </GridLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

page1.js

```
exports.goToMotelDetail = function(args) {
    var id = args.object.motelId;
    var name = args.object.name;
    var navigationEntry = {
        moduleName: "views/motel-detail/motel-detail",
        context: {
            info: "some string to test",
            id: id,
            name: name
        },
        animated: false
    };
    var topmost = frameModule.topmost();
    topmost.navigate(navigationEntry);
}
```

page2.xml

```
<Page  navigatedTo="navigatedTo">
    <Page.ActionBar>
        <ActionBar title="{{ name }}" />
    </Page.ActionBar>
    <Label text="Motel detail" />
</Page>
```

page2.js

```
exports.navigatedTo = function (args) {
  var page = args.object;
  var dataItem = page.navigationContext;
  page.bindingContext = dataItem;
};
```

The thing is: when i click on an item the app navigate to page2, but doesn't show the name tha was sent within the context and if i try with info, it works.
I can't figure out how to make it work.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because you did not get the `name` from `args.object.name`. Have you tried to console.log the id and the name? The reason it show the info is that because you set the info in the context to a string, while the name might be nothing.

I also think there is something wrong here in your code:

```
<ListView items="{{ motels }}"
              row="1"
              id="motelsList"
              motelId="{{ id }}"
              name="{{ name }}"
              itemTap="goToMotelDetail">
```

ListView does not have such properties "motelId" or "name", and these are also should be inside the ListView.itemTemplate as I understand.

One more thing, you put the "itemTap" inside the ListView tags. It mean that the object that you get from the `args.object` will be the instance of ListView, which does not have such a property like `name` thus you don't have the name sent to page2

Comment: When I console.log the name and id I get [object object], but if I move the function to a label and put the name and id as a label property I get the right values